# How could I save my input from a check box wherein when I check only one option on the box it gave me an error

Tags: python, django

How could I save my input from a check box wherein when I check option1 of the box and save it it gives me an error saying there is no value on option2 or vice versa. But when i marked them both. I was able to save it on the database, problem is on my database it should only show either value of 1 or 0 and null if there is no input.

Here is my html code for now.

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group bmd-form-group">
        <input type="checkbox" name="is_regular" value="1"> Regular<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="is_special" value="0"> Special<br>
    </div>
</div>
```

Model forms

```
class Save_Holiday_Form(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Holiday
        fields = ['holiday_id', 'holiday_name', 'is_regular', 'is_special', 'date_start', 'date_end']
```

Views.py

```
def add_holidays(request):
    holiday_name = request.POST['holiday_name']
    date_start = request.POST['date_start']
    date_end = request.POST['date_end']
    is_regular = request.POST['is_regular']
    is_special = request.POST['is_special']

    holiday_info = Holiday(
            holiday_name=holiday_name,
            date_start=date_start,
            date_end=date_end,
            is_regular=is_regular,
            is_special=is_special
            )
    holiday_info.save()
    return render(request, 'holidays.html')
```

Comment: Please also include your `Holiday` model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> it should only show either value of 1 or 0 and null if there is no input

Assuming the `is_regular` and `is_special` **accept null values**, you can use:

```
def add_holidays(request):
    holiday_name = request.POST['holiday_name']
    date_start = request.POST['date_start']
    date_end = request.POST['date_end']
    is_regular = request.POST.get('is_regular', None)  # <-------
    is_special = request.POST.get('is_special', None)  # <-------

    holiday_info = Holiday(
            holiday_name=holiday_name,
            date_start=date_start,
            date_end=date_end,
            is_regular=is_regular,
            is_special=is_special
            )
    holiday_info.save()
    return render(request, 'holidays.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can group together the Checkbox for same name:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
           <div class="form-group bmd-form-group">
              <input type="checkbox" name="is_regular_or_special" value="1"> Regular<br>
                      <input type="checkbox" name="is_regular_or_special" value="0"> Special<br>
            </div>
</div>
```

Then you may check the value in views.py:

```
def add_holidays(request):
holiday_name = request.POST['holiday_name']
date_start = request.POST['date_start']
date_end = request.POST['date_end']
is_regular_or_special= request.POST['is_regular_or_special']
```

So the value will be either o or 1. o for special and 1 for regular.

I think you do not need the two database field for it. You can use one field for hold the value instead of two fields.

Also if you need to show value you can easily pick value from field and depending on the value you may decide is it regular or special